# for loop till angls match C#

Tags: c#, cursor-position

Basically I want to move my mouse till the to angles match.
This is what I got so far (doesn't work):

```
for (eyeangle != angleVert)
{
    if (eyeangle < angleVert)
    {
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y - 10);
    }

    if (eyeangle > angleVert)
    {
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y + 10);
    }
}
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: You must have some sort of array or collection to iterate to

Comment: okay so I would do something like: `for(int i = 0; angleVert != eyeangle; i++)   {                    if (eyeangle < angleVert)
                    {
                        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
                        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y - i);
                    }`

Comment: I think you might be wanting a `while` loop, but be careful: If you logic is bad you will end up with an infinite loop. You need to make sure the condition will either eventually definitely be true, or you have a way to break the loop

Comment: @jmc this isn't java but c#

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman really? well, can you show me a for loop with this syntax? `for (eyeangle != angleVert)`

Comment: You can `break;` from a for loop when you need to.

Comment: @jmc No, ask the author what he tried at this place. But the language tag and the rest of the code cleary is **c#**

Comment: Voting as offtopic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman exactly why im telling him to iterate over an array or collection if he intends to use a for loop. what's your argument?

Comment: @Dr. Lel: As a side note: Use [Maths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions). It's your friend ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `while` instead `for`

```
while (eyeangle != angleVert)
{
    if (eyeangle < angleVert)
    {
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y - 10);
    }

    if (eyeangle > angleVert)
    {
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y + 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to update `eyeangle` as well as `angleVert` somehow since both `eyeangle` and `angleVert` look like *fields*.